# Rest Webservice is not consuming the json input

Tags: json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, curl

I have a rest controller.

```
package com.raghu.examples.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.raghu.examples.dto.Employee;
import com.raghu.examples.dto.SearchCriteria;
import com.raghu.examples.service.IEmployeeService;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    IEmployeeService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/employee/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
    public Employee[] getPersonDetail(SearchCriteria se) {
        System.out.println("search :=" + se);
        Employee[] emps = service.getEmployee(se);
        System.out.println("employee := " + emps);
        return emps;
    }

}
```

I have the following DTO.

```
package com.raghu.examples.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Address implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5727060737690659841L;

    private String streetAddress;

    private String address1;

    private String address2;

    private Integer doorNumber;

    private String city;

    private String country;


    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }


    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }


    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }


    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }


    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }


    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }


    public Integer getDoorNumber() {
        return doorNumber;
    }


    public void setDoorNumber(Integer doorNumber) {
        this.doorNumber = doorNumber;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }


    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.raghu.examples.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Employee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4353052168060257585L;

    private String name;

    private Integer number;

    private String age;

    private Address address;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }


    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }






}
```

SearchCriteria.java

```
package com.raghu.examples.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class SearchCriteria implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6218970698738121299L;

    private Employee employee;

    private String[] city;


    public SearchCriteria(Employee employee, String[] city) {
        super();
        this.employee = employee;
        this.city = city;
    }


    public SearchCriteria() {
        super();
    }




    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }


    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }


    public String[] getCity() {
        return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String[] city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchCriteria [employee=" + employee + ", city=" + Arrays.toString(city) + "]";
    }



}
```

IEmployeeService.java

```
package com.raghu.examples.service;

import com.raghu.examples.dto.Employee;
import com.raghu.examples.dto.SearchCriteria;


public interface IEmployeeService {

    public Employee[]  getEmployee(SearchCriteria e);

}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
package com.raghu.examples.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.raghu.examples.dto.Address;
import com.raghu.examples.dto.Employee;
import com.raghu.examples.dto.SearchCriteria;

@Component
public class EmployeeService implements IEmployeeService {

    public Employee[] getEmployee(SearchCriteria e) {
        Employee[] emps = new Employee[2]; 
      if (e != null && e.getCity() != null && e.getCity()[0].equals("Bangalore")) {
          Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.setName("Raghu");
          Address add = new Address();
          add.setAddress1("Marathahalli");
          emp.setAddress(add);
          emps[0]=emp;

      } else {
          //no code
      }
      return emps;
    }

}
```

Now when i test my rest webservice using curl or firefox rest client, the SearchCriteria object is not getting populated.

I am passing the json input to the restcontroller after setting the content-type as json.

1. Testing with Curl:

   curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --data '{ "city" : ["Bangalore" , "chennai"] , "employee" : { "name" : "raghu" }}' http://localhost:8080/rest-example/data/employee/
2. Output:

   ```
   search :=SearchCriteria [employee=null, city=null]
   employee := [Lcom.raghu.examples.dto.Employee;@47f84948
   ```

Why employee and city are null?
json is valid, is there any other problem with my json input?

2. Rest Client:
   [image]

SOP Output in controller:

```
search :=SearchCriteria [employee=null, city=null]
employee := [Lcom.raghu.examples.dto.Employee;@1a6cc1d3
```

Why employee and city are null in SearchCriteria object?

Comment: Ok. It worked.     public Employee[] getPersonDetail(@RequestBody SearchCriteria se) { } @RequestBody  was missing.  After correcting this, i'm able to get the value of the searchcriteria.

Comment: Have you tried adding getters and setters for all fields in SearchCriteria and all classes it uses?

Comment: morsor ,  all required getters and setters were in place already. only issue though is in  getPersonDetail(SearchCriteria se)  of  EmployeeController, i have missed to add @RequestBody i.e.) getPersonDetail (@RequestBody SearchCriteria se). This has solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid, check you missed starting double quotes to **ore**

the following is the valid json:

```
{
    "employee": {
        "address1": "marthahalli"
    },
    "city": [
        "ore",
        "chennai"
    ]
}
```

[here](http://jsonlint.com/) you can check whether ur json valid or not

Comment: Apologies. Not Pasted properly. Edited the question to pass the correct json. it is still an issue.